# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put

Tags: android, out-of-memory, okhttp

I am using `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0` in my application for API calling Also I am using `io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3` for Socket connection. Now I am getting following error `Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed` on [Fabric](https://fabric.io). I don't know where this error is happening,

is this issue is due to uploading a large image? I am sending base64 images(width "1024" or height as "1024") as multipart RequestBody.

Here is my Sample Api call with Image,

```
RequestBody nameBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), name);

RequestBody profilePic = null;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mProfilePicPath);
if (bitmap != null) {
    String base64Image = String.valueOf("data:image/png;base64," + encodeImage(bitmap).replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), ""));
    profilePic = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), base64Image);
}
RequestBody licenseFront = null;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCarDriveOnePath);
if (bitmap != null) {
    String base64Image = String.valueOf("data:image/png;base64," + encodeImage(bitmap).replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), ""));
    licenseFront = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), base64Image);
}
RequestBody licenseBack = null;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCarDriveTwoPath);
if (bitmap != null) {
    String base64Image = String.valueOf("data:image/png;base64," + encodeImage(bitmap).replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), ""));
    licenseBack = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), base64Image);
}

//API Call
ApiClient.updateDriverDetails(nameBody , profilePic, licenseFront, licenseBack).enqueue(new Callback<UpdateDriverResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UpdateDriverResponse> call, Response<UpdateDriverResponse> response) {
        Log.d("UpdateDriver", "Success");
    //Here Comes the parsing of API response        
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UpdateDriverResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("UpdateDriver", "Error");
    }
});
```

Using the above Api call I am uploading name, profile pic, License front and back images,

```
       Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
       at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put(ConnectionPool.java:149)
       at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$1.put(OkHttpClient.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:129)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Could you post your code

Comment: @sJy :  I don't know where this error is happening. I found this error on Fabric which I mentioned on my question. Which code you need? Also this error is happened once and it is on Samsung Galaxy A5.

Comment: Your Retrofit builder code along with one api call code

Comment: @sJy: Please see the question, I updated with api call

Comment: Your BitmapFactory.decodeFile() will be heavy as it allocates memory for constructed bitmap. Retrofit already have MultipartBody.Part  which you can use rather than creating a Bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by resizing by calling `transform()` on `onActivityResult()`,

```
// This method is to resize image.
public Bitmap transform(String image_file_path) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Photo transform :: " + image_file_path);
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            if (image_file_path != null && !image_file_path.isEmpty()) {
                File image_file = new File(image_file_path);
                if (image_file != null && image_file.exists()) {

                    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
                    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    //options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    options.inSampleSize = 5;

                    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file_path, options);
                    if (source != null) {
                        boolean isLandscape = source.getWidth() > source.getHeight();
                        int newWidth, newHeight;
                        if (isLandscape) {
                            newWidth = 1024;
                            newHeight = Math.round(((float) newWidth / source.getWidth()) * source.getHeight());
                        } else {
                            newHeight = 1024;
                            newWidth = Math.round(((float) newHeight / source.getHeight()) * source.getWidth());
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "Resized : " + source.getWidth() + "x" + source.getHeight() + " to " + newWidth + "x" + newHeight);

                        result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, newWidth, newHeight, true);
                        //result = ImageResize.resize(image_file, newWidth, newHeight, ResizeMode.AUTOMATIC);

                        if (result != source)
                            source.recycle();

                        writeImage(result, image_file.getPath());

                        if (image_file_path == mCurrentCBTImagePath || image_file_path.equals(mCurrentCBTImagePath)) {
                            CbtEncodedString = encodeImage(result);
                            mPresenter.setCBTbaseEncodedString(CbtEncodedString);
                        } else if (image_file_path == mCurrentCourierImagePath || image_file_path.equals(mCurrentCourierImagePath)) {
                            CourierEncodedString = encodeImage(result);
                            mPresenter.setCourierbaseEncodedString(CourierEncodedString);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "transform (Resize Image)::" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OutOfMemoryError: transform" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }


// This method is to save the resized image.
    public static void writeImage(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            File imagePath = new File(path);
            if (imagePath.exists())
                imagePath.delete();
            out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```